# Cannot render any icons / images Tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, desktop-application

I'm developing a Python desktop application using Tkinter.
I've been having issues when loading images.

[image]

The picture above shows the top border of the main window. It is supposed to show an icon there, but it doesn't.

I've been searching a bit regarding this issue. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
app_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='absolute_path/app_icon.png')
self.iconphoto(True, app_icon)
```

The code above apparently is loading properly, no error messages shown, but no image is attached next to the title of the window.

I've also used iconbitmap with an .xbm file. (I used a converter here, I didn't change the extension only)

```
self.iconbitmap('@assets/icons/app_icon.xbm')
```

Here is the same problem as before, no error shown nor no icon rendered. I purposely inserted a typo in the path to check that this line was doing something and I got the following error.

```
_tkinter.TclError: error reading bitmap file "assets/icos/app_icon.xbm"
```

So the path is correct in the previous example.

I also tried loading the image with PILLOW but I got the same result as I explained before.

This problem also happens when I try to load png images, icons for buttons, etc, so I'm not able to add any visual enhancements to the application, just text.

Notice that it is not even loading the default icon that the library sets. (the feather icon)

Sidenote, the application is implemented with classes, this is the main window, the last two lines are supposed to set the icon for the application.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height =  self.winfo_screenheight()
        center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
        self.title('Admin')
        self.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        app_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='/home/user/Source/admin/assets/icons/app_icon.png')
        self.iconphoto(True, app_icon)
```

Here are my specs

OS Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Python 3.10.12, Tkinter 8.6.12

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Comment: yes, it works for showing images inside labels, but I'm still unable to set an application icon. It just doesn't render. I'm not sure if the icon needs to be a specific size. I've already tried 16x16 32x32. Maybe the icon is there, but not visible.
Another example is inside menus, there you can set a property called image, and if a set an image, it doesn't render and the text is not visible. The same happen for buttons.
I saved a reference to the image as the other stackoverflow posts said but only labels worked.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce these problems.

Comment: It may be due to that `Wayland` is used instead of `X11` in your ubuntu.